# Discord.js cannot process a msg.reply

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, discord.js

I'm trying to make a script that converts chars from my file and converts them into dices, but the problem is that the script puts an error every time when 'k' for loop is longer than 3 then msg.reply() cannot process it and drops an error. Script here:

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require("path");
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js')

exports.run = (bot, msg, args) => {
    var litery = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÄËÏÖÜÅÆŒØ12345⨀ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ67890↑↓←→'//40
    var dice = [
        '<:Oginiowa:1019968984646439013>',
        '<:Elektryczna:1019968982930968696>',
        '<:Wiatrowa:1019968981349711973>',
        '<:Zatruta:1019968979760054302>',
        '<:Lodowa:1019968978292047872>',
        '<:Hazardowa:1019968972889788438>',
        '<:Zepsuta:1019968975129550928>',
        '<:Zelazna:1019968976941498418>',
        '<:Sejfowa:1019968986391269457>',
        '<:Minowa:1019981938775298068>',
        '<:Jasna:1019981936501997608>',
        '<:Cierna:1019981934601973830>',
        '<:Uszkodzona:1019981933066850314>',
        '<:Critical:1019981931401715722>',
        '<:Energy:1019981929409413131>',
        '<:Poswiecenie:1019981946127929406>',
        '<:Strzala:1019981944261464186>',
        '<:LosowyWzrost:1019981942499844187>',
        '<:Procna:1019981940700479668>',
        '<:Death:1020026235910377503>',
        '<:Teleport:1020026233486061618>',
        '<:Laser:1020026229946065069>',
        '<:Mimic:1020026227404316773>',
        '<:Infect:1020026224648658944>',
        '<:ModifiedElectric:1020026222098518106>',
        '<:Absorb:1020026219498049536>',
        '<:MightyWind:1020026216301989888>',
        '<:Switch:1020026213252739092',
        '<:Gear:1020026210786496633>',
        '<:Wave:1020026207426838669>',
        '<:Flame:1020026204532789330>',
        '<:Uleczajaca:1020026202133626930>',
        '<:Klonowa:1020026199264739429>',
        '<:UszkodzonyWzrost:1020026196681052322>',
        '<:Hojna:1020026194067996753>',
        '<:Kamien:1020026191878570034>',
        '<:Szybkostrzalowa:1020026189533958274>',
        '<:Berserkerowa:1020026187445178439>',
        '<:Sniezkowa:1020026185159282768>',
        '<:Whim:1020026241790779413>',
        '<:Pinball:1020026238678609961>',
        '<:Nuclear:1020402792311050400>',
        '<:Landmine:1020402795888791646>',
        '<:SandSwamp:1020402798409555968>',
        '<:Joker:1020402800234090496>',
        '<:HolySword:1020402802129899570>',
        '<:Hell:1020402803941843135>',
        '<:Shield:1020402805934133338>',
        '<:Blizzard:1020402807913857055>',
        '<:Growth:1020402810115866704>',
        '<:Summoner:1020402812364017735>',
        '<:Solar:1020402814733783050>',
        '<:Assassin:1020402816898039888>',
        '<:Atomic:1020402819372691607>',
        '<:Gun:1020402821922824262>',
        '<:Typhoon:1020402825802567881>',
        '<:Supplement:1020402827455119470>',
        '<:Metastasis:1020402823919317012>',
        '<:Time:1020402829766168668>',
        '<:Combo:1020402830890246146>',
        '<:Lunar:1020402833780121712>',
        '<:Flow:1020402836338655252>',
        '<:Star:1020402839132061757>',
        '<:ix10:1020402768776810517>',
        '<:Silence:1020402767459786752>',
        '<:Royal:1020402770785869995>',
        '<:YinYang:1020402772702662816>',
        '<:Scope:1020402775311519944>',
        '<:Bubble:1020402777157009519>',
        '<:Guardian:1020402778834743450>',
        '<:Overheat:1020402780617314354>',
        '<:Earthquake:1020402782970323004>',
        '<:Timewinder:1020402784874545182>',
        '<:Recharge:1020402786531295252>',
        '<:Compression:1020402788464857119>',
        '<:LightningCloud:1020402790398443570>'
    ];
    var ln = dice.length
    if(args[0] === 'deck') {
        if (args[1] === 'random') {
            var sel;
            var send;
            var used = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                sel = dice[Math.floor(Math.random() * ln)] 
                if(used.includes(sel)) {
                    i = i - 1
                    continue;
                }
                if (i == 0) { send = sel + ' ' }
                else if (i == 4) { send = send + sel }
                else { send = send + sel + ' ' }
                used.push(sel)
            }
            msg.reply(send)
        } else if (!Number.isNaN(+args[1])) {
            let decks = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '..\\decks.c'), 'utf-8');
            let perdeck = decks.split('\r\n')
            let ln = perdeck.length
            if(args[1] < 1 || args[1] > ln) {
                msg.reply('That deck doesn\'t exist')
                console.log(ln)
            } else {
                let seg = perdeck[args[1]-1].split(' ')
                if (seg[0] === 'CO-OP') {
                    let dicesend = ' ';
                    let dicesend2 = ' ';
                    for(var j = 1; j < 6; j++) {
                        /*if(!dicesend) { var dicesend = dice[litery.indexOf(litery.charAt(k))] }
                        else { var dicesend = dicesend + dice[litery.indexOf(litery.charAt(k))] }*/
                        if(dicesend === ' ') { dicesend = dice[litery.indexOf(seg[2].charAt(j-1))] }
                        else { dicesend = dicesend + dice[litery.indexOf(seg[2].charAt(j-1))] }
                    }
                    for(var k = 1; k < 3; k++) {
                        /*if(!dicesend) { var dicesend = dice[litery.indexOf(litery.charAt(k))] }
                        else { var dicesend = dicesend + dice[litery.indexOf(litery.charAt(k))] }*/
                        if(dicesend2 === ' ') { dicesend2 = dice[litery.indexOf(seg[3].charAt(k-1))] }
                        else { dicesend2 = dicesend2 + dice[litery.indexOf(seg[3].charAt(k-1))] }
                    }
                    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
                        embed.setTitle(seg[5])
                        embed.setDescription(`Type: ${seg[0]}`)
                        embed.addFields({ name: `Main:      ${dicesend}\nSupport: ${dicesend2}`, value: seg[4] })
                        embed.setColor(seg[1])
                    msg.reply({embeds: [embed]})
                    console.log(dicesend)
                    console.log(dicesend2)
                } else {
                    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
                        embed.setTitle(seg[4])
                        embed.setDescription(`Type: ${seg[0]}`)
                        embed.addFields({ name: seg[2], value: seg[3] })
                        embed.setColor(seg[1])
                    msg.reply({embeds: [embed]})
                }
            }
        } else {
            msg.reply('This subcommand doesn\'t exist')
        }
    }
}
```

And the error:

```js
C:\Users\Tomek\Music\DiscordBot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:76
    throw this.error;
    ^

CombinedPropertyError: Received one or more errors
    at ArrayValidator.handle (C:\Users\Tomek\Music\DiscordBot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:463:70)
    at ArrayValidator.parse (C:\Users\Tomek\Music\DiscordBot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:142:88)
    at EmbedBuilder.addFields (C:\Users\Tomek\Music\DiscordBot\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\messages\embed\Embed.cjs:17:42)
    at exports.run (C:\Users\Tomek\Music\DiscordBot\modules\randomdice.js:130:31)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Tomek\Music\DiscordBot\main.js:91:21)
    at Client.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\Tomek\Music\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:23:14)
    at module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\Tomek\Music\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\Tomek\Music\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:352:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\Tomek\Music\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:481:22) {
  errors: [
    [
      0,
      CombinedPropertyError: Received one or more errors
          at ObjectValidator.handleIgnoreStrategy (C:\Users\Tomek\Music\DiscordBot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:1223:72)
          at ObjectValidator.handleStrategy (C:\Users\Tomek\Music\DiscordBot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:1102:47)
          at ObjectValidator.handle (C:\Users\Tomek\Music\DiscordBot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:1193:17)
          at ObjectValidator.run (C:\Users\Tomek\Music\DiscordBot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:128:23)
          at ArrayValidator.handle (C:\Users\Tomek\Music\DiscordBot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:457:37)
          at ArrayValidator.parse (C:\Users\Tomek\Music\DiscordBot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:142:88)
          at EmbedBuilder.addFields (C:\Users\Tomek\Music\DiscordBot\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\messages\embed\Embed.cjs:17:42)
          at exports.run (C:\Users\Tomek\Music\DiscordBot\modules\randomdice.js:130:31)
          at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Tomek\Music\DiscordBot\main.js:91:21)
          at Client.emit (node:events:525:35) {
        errors: [ [ 'name', [ExpectedConstraintError] ] ]
      }
    ]
  ]
}

Node.js v18.8.0
```

If i don't know a simple thing then sorry, I'm a newbie that knows how to code but may not know certain things, Thanks for any help!

Comment: The problem is not the forloop but rather how you logic implements an index of `3`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i don't know what you're talking about i just don't know how to set it to 6 and so that will work

Comment: I highly recommend you take the time to learn JavaScript before creating a bot in DJS. It's understandable that you could be too excited to create and not want to sit down and go through the basics. However, you're only limiting yourself and what you can create. You wouldn't want to try and build a house before learning how to use a hammer would you?

Comment: Okay, but for now i think i don't need to learn it, for discord.js if i didn't know something then i would learn it, but this is just a small issue BUT i found out that the error isn't from the forloop but from the msg.reply function because the dicesend2 is formatted correctly, also it doesn't match the character limit. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Found the issue, EmbedBuilder have trouble rendering that much emojis in one field